# Let Cordova access app with http://localhost instead of file://android_asset

Tags: cordova, phonegap

Can I make Cordova use a lcoal webserver to serve the contents of /www or am I stuck with using file://

The Problem is that loging in with Facebook seems to need a URL, and when using file:// there is no URL to handle.

Turning to a native plugin helps, but if the User has no Native Facebook installed, the problem still persists.

This error comes up:

Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to leverage a native plugin. If the Facebook app is not installed, it will fall back to using a baked in web-based authentication built for use in mobile apps. See https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4.